# USB SSD Backdoor command issue

Tags: malware, ssd

In our company we have many SpeedFaster 2TB USB SSDs. They were working perfectly until our endpoint protection software was updated. Currently they work only for a few seconds and are then blocked with the following message:
"SCSI target responds to known malware command (jmshal E078)"

Initially I assumed some malware was found on the drive and I fully erased it using dd on a linux system. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. Later we noticed that all SSDs of this type stopped working, so it likely has nothing to do with the data on the disk. Surprisingly, the 1TB version of the same SSD still works well.

Does anybody know how we can solve this problem? The vendor is less than helpful, they only recommended buying a new USB cable which, as expected, solved nothing.

Comment: You asked both the drive and endpoint protection software provider?

Comment: From the message, it appears to be a hardware issue. The EPP is freaking out at the hardware. Add an exception.

Comment: Weird googling the "malware command" seems to yield no results...